# How to use findViewById with fragments in mainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I took a look at the other questions talking about this problem and what I learnt is that my problem is there because I try to find a view that isn't in the actual displayed view (I guess).

But I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Here is my `MainActivity.java` where the error appears with `final ListView list...`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private Context context = this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //-------------------------------------- Apero list ---------------------------
        ArrayList<AperoVersion> aperoList = new ArrayList<AperoVersion>();
        initList(aperoList);
        AperoAdapter adapter = new AperoAdapter(this, R.layout.apero_list_layout, aperoList);
        final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_apero);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                AperoVersion selectedItem = (AperoVersion) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.v("CustomAdapterExemple", "Selected apero: " + selectedItem.getName());
            }
        });
    }
```

Then I have the `fragment_home`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_apero"
        android:layout_width="407dp"
        android:layout_height="598dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="136dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.043" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.lapero/com.example.lapero.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a
>   null object reference

Comment: activity has no business touching fragment views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list_apero` is in `fragment_home` and not in `activity_main`.

`findViewById(R.id.list_apero)` in the activity is returning null.

You should set the adapter in the Fragment, not in the Activity.

Comment: But then the displayed view wouldn't be the right one no ?

Comment: Where is `fragment_home` layout used? Isn't it the layout of a Fragment? On the Activity load the Fragment and then on the Fragment set it's Adapter as you have access to all its layout in `onCreateView`.

Comment: ahhh okay yes I see I had to change it on the fragment instead of mainActivity

Comment: That's right, there is an example of activity with fragment in the same Android Studio going to `New / Activity / Fragment + ViewModel`. This activity is going to load that fragment and the fragment with that use of `supportFragmentManager` and then the Fragment has access to the view inside `onCreateView` if you save the result of inflate to return it later. You can use `findViewById` there and perform operations and/or save the object references.